# Application to display food names

Tags: xaml, xamarin

I am trying to learn, and I want to create a application that works like this: When they click a button, it will choose a random food(for example baked potato), and whey they click the label(or button) with the food, the recipe for that food will open in a browser.

I have tried making a list or some sort, but not sure how to do this:

```
<local:People x:Food="ArrayFood">
                <sys:String Pasta="One" URL="http://food.com/pasta"/>
                <sys:String Corn="Two" URL="http://food.com/corn"/>          
                <sys:String Salsa="Three" URL="http://food.com/Salsa"/>
            </local:People>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem you're running into is the String type doesn't have those properties of Pasta, Corn, Salsa, or URL.

Probably the easiest thing is not to store that in the resource dictionary at all. I would store a list of custom objects in the ViewModel.

Something like:

```
public class Food
{
   public Food() {}
   public Food(string name, string url) {Name=name;Url = url;}
   public string Name {get; set;}
   public string Url {get; set;}
}

public class MyViewModel
{
    public List<Food> Foods {get;set;} = new List<Food>
    {
      new Food("Corn", "http://..."),
      new Food("Pasta", "http://blah/pasta" )
    }
    .. other view model stuff ..
}
```

Then bind it to a list view. When they tap, then visit the url

Comment: Ohh, so I have to do this in the `.cs` file. I understand :) How do I choose a random Food from the list, and display the text on a button? And when they click the button, the link is opened?

Comment: Think of it like this: The ViewModel holds the data. The UI binds to that data. So your ViewModel may have a SelectedFood property, and the button's Text is bound to the Food's Name. Then your problem (and it is a good one for you to solve on your own) is how you select a random food from the list and set it in the selected food.

Comment: What do I put in the `MainPage.xaml`? Only the `<Button x:FoodName="FoodButtonName"
                   Text="%foodname%"` ?

Comment: I think you need to take a step back and fully understand how MVVM works. This explains it pretty well, and should allow you to create the architecture you need. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/xaml/xaml-basics/data-bindings-to-mvvm

Comment: I think I figured it out now, but how do I simply open URL? Since this is for both iOS and Android, I cant use `System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("http://www.google.no/");` to open a link.

Comment: Yes, just found `Device.OpenUri` :)